# Index for Number in Mongo

Tags: indexing

I  am trying to keep indexing for number in mongodb but I cannot find how to do it. I have tried to keep for text in following way
db.user.createIndex(
   {
     content: "text",
     "users.comments": "text",
     "users.profiles": "text"
   }
)

So similar to text (i.e. for string) is there any type for number.
I have searched in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of creating a normal index you are creating "full text" indexes to search for keys,

a normal (compound) index will be

```
db.user.createIndex( {"users.comments": 1, "users.profiles": 1})
```

If it's about normal index, it can be created in same manner for number fields.

```
db.user.createIndex( {"numberField": 1})
```